# Combine and sort two arrays with different size. Then, replace them with 0 and 1 in C program

Tags: c, arrays, int

This is the last part in a huge project. The question of my project is to code the program in C which can convert from decimal to binary. I did everything, however, I stuck with one part. After separating into two arrays - one array contains the positions of 1 and another one includes the positions of 0. For example with number 19. My arrays have:

`array1 = {4,1,0} //which are pow(2,4),pow(2,1), and pow(1,0)`. Obviously, these numbers should be replaced with number 1.

Similarly, `array2 = {3,2} // which are pow(2,3) and pow(2,2)` indicate the numbers should be substituted with number 0.

My question is: Is there any way to combine and sort these two arrays into one new array. Eventually, we need to compare the value of the new array to seek for the repeated value to replace 0 and 1.

Example: lets look at number 19;

```
array1 = {4,1,0};

array2 = {3,2};

newarray = {4,3,2,1,0};

expectedoutput = {1 0 0 1 1};
```

Below is my code to convert from decimal to binary, but it does not accomplish due to the unsolved question above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int number,number1,y,i,total=0,z,a,ya,a1,m,n,count1=0,count2=0;
    int  array1[10];
    int  array2[10];
    float x,xa;
    printf("Enter the number you want to convert from decimal integer to binary: \n");
    scanf(" %d",&number1);
    number = number1;

x = log2f(number1);
y = floor(x);



while(y!=0){
    for (m=0;m<=100;m++){


        x = log2f(number1);
        y = floor(x);







        number1 = number1 - pow(2,y);

        //array1 = (int * )malloc(y * sizeof(int));

        array1[m] = y;

        count1 += 1;


        if (number1==0){
            break;
        }
    }

}


x = log2f(number);
y = floor(x);



for (i=0;i<=y;i++){
    z = pow(2,i);
    total += z;

}
a = total - number;
a1=a;
xa = log2f(a);
ya = floor(xa);

while(ya!=0){
    for (n=0;n<=100;n++){


        xa = log2f(a);
        ya = floor(xa);







        a = a - pow(2,ya);



        array2[n] = ya;

        count2 += 1;


        if (a==0){
            ya = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You show `array1 = {4,1,0};

array2 = {3,2};

newarray = {4,3,2,1,0};

expectedoutput = {1 0 0 1 1};` — but you can't create the `expectedoutput` from `newarray` because you don't know whether the 4 should be a 1 or a 0 without looking somewhere else (presumably `array1` and `array2`) for the information.  Maybe you should record negative numbers in `newarray` for zero bits and positive numbers for one bits, and sort by absolute value.  That then leaves you with a problem of negative zero; maybe number the bits from 1 so it isn't a problem after all?

Comment: Lots of ways of doing it. One is to set up a structure which consists of a value plus a 1 or 0 tag indicating which sub-array the datum originated from. Another is to sort the arrays independently then merge. Another, summing integers, is to multiply by two, set the last bit, sort, then undo.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both `array1` and `array2` are sorted in descending order, one approach to create the binary array `expectedoutput` is by continuously comparing the first elements of array1 and array2. Whichever is greater of the two first elements will be the value that gets sent to `expectedoutput` as either a `1` or a `0`. The greater first element is then removed from its containing array. Here is an illustration:

```
/*
    expectedoutput = {}
    array1 = {4, 1, 0}
    array2 = {3, 2}

    procedure: --------------------------------------------------------------------
    (any element from array1 is added to expectedoutput as 1, and from array2 as 0)

        {4, 1, 0} ------- ------- {3, 2}
         ^               |         ^
                       4 > 3     --> array1 = {1, 0} , expectedoutput = {1}
                         |
           {1, 0} ------- ------- {3, 2}
            ^            |         ^
                       1 < 3     --> array2 = {2}, expectedoutput = {1, 0}
                         |
           {1, 0} ------- ------- {2}
            ^            |         ^
                       1 < 2     --> array2 = {}, expectedoutput = {1, 0, 0}
                         |
           {1, 0} ------- ------- {}
                         |
                         ----------> array2 is empty, so add 1 to expectedoutput 
                                        until array1 becomes empty
                                     Now: array1 = {}, array2 = {}, 
                                          expectedoutput = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}
*/
```

Since we are dealing with 1s and 0s, it would be a good idea to set empty arrays to some invalid value like `-1`. You can use `memset` at initial declaration as `int array1[10]; memset(array1, -1, sizeof(array1));` so that later on `array1 = {4, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}`. Similarly with any other array.

Now we can implement the above procedure by writing two functions: one that removes the first element from an array, and another that creates `expectedoutput` using two arrays.

To remove first element of an array:

```
// remove_first(arr, len) removes the first element of arr[len]
// For example: arr[5] = {3, 2, 6, -1, -1}
//              remove_first(arr, 5) 
//              arr[5] == {2, 6, -1, -1, -1}
void remove_first(int *arr, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len-1; ++i) {
        arr[i] = arr[i+1];
    }
    arr[len-1] = -1;
}
```

To create binary array:

```
// create_binary_array(arr, arr1, len1, arr2, len2) updates arr by setting
//   its elements to either 1 or 0, using arr1 and arr2
// For example: arr[10] = {}, arr1[10] = {3, 1}, arr2[10] = {2}
//              create_binary_array(arr, arr1, 10, arr2, 10)
//              arr == {1, 0, 1}, arr1 == {}, arr2 == {}
void create_binary_array(int *arr, int *arr1, int len1, int *arr2, int len2) {
    int i = 0;
    while (arr1[0] != -1 || arr2[0] != -1) {
        if (arr1[0] == -1) {
            while (arr2[0] != -1) {
                arr[i] = 0;
                ++i;
                remove_first(arr2, len2);
            }
        } else if (arr2[0] == -1) {
            while (arr1[0] != -1) {
                arr[i] = 1;
                ++i;
                remove_first(arr1, len1);
            }
        } else if (arr1[0] > arr2[0]) {
            arr[i] = 1;
            ++i;
            remove_first(arr1, len1);
        } else if (arr1[0] < arr2[0]) {
            arr[i] = 0;
            ++i;
            remove_first(arr2, len2);
        }
    }
}
```

so now you can have:

```
int expectedoutput[10];
memset(expectedoutput, -1, sizeof(expectedoutput));

int array1[10] = {4, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
int array2[10] = {3, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};

create_binary_array(expectedoutput, array1, 10, array2, 10);

// Now: expectedoutput == {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}
```